# index.php not linking to single.php single page post

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

Hello guys I'm working on a wordpress theme/template and I'm having problems when clicking on blog post title in index.html. It will redirect me to correct link on address bar however, single.php is not displaying anything. I'm not sure if the page is getting called or what's actually going on. If you can weight your 2cents thanks here's the link to wordpress blog: http://pctechtips.org/testblog
index.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <!-- jumbotron -->
      <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="display-4"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>
          <p class="lead"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></p>
        </div>
      </div>

    <!-- /jumbotron -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">

        <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
        <div class="col-md-8">

         <?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

          <!-- Blog Post -->
          <div class="mb-4">
            <div class="card-body">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <h2 class="card-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                </a>
                <p class="blog-post-meta">
                    <?php echo Date('M d, Y'); ?> by <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a>
                </p>
                <!-- feature image -->
                <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                <div class="post-thumb">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
              <p class="card-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            </div>
          </div>

      <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php else : ?>
          <p><?php __('No Post Found!'); ?></p>
      <?php endif; ?>

          <!-- Pagination -->
          <ul class="pagination justify-content-center mb-4">
            <li class="page-item">
              <a class="page-link" href="#">&larr; Older</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item disabled">
              <a class="page-link" href="#">Newer &rarr;</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>

        <!-- Sidebar Widgets Column -->
        <div class="col-md-4">

          <!-- Search Widget -->
          <div class="card my-4">
            <h5 class="card-header">Search</h5>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Go!</button>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Categories Widget -->
          <div class="card my-4">
            <h5 class="card-header">Categories</h5>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Web Design</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">HTML</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Freebies</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">CSS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Tutorials</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Side Widget -->
          <div class="card my-4">
            <h5 class="card-header">Side Widget</h5>
            <div class="card-body">
              You can put anything you want inside of these side widgets. They are easy to use, and feature the new Bootstrap 4 card containers!
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

single.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <!-- jumbotron -->
      <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="display-4"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>
          <p class="lead"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    <!-- /jumbotron -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
        <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
        <div class="blog-post col-md-8"> 

         <?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

          <!-- Blog Post -->
          <div class="blog-post-title mb-4">            
                    <h2 class="card-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <p class="blog-post-meta">
                    <?php echo Date('M d, Y'); ?> by <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a>
                </p> 
                <!-- feature image -->
                <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                <div class="post-thumb">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
              <p class="card-text"><?php the_content(); ?></p> 
              <hr>
              <!-- comments -->
              <?php comments_templates(); ?>
          </div>

      <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php else : ?>
          <p><?php __('No Post Found!'); ?></p>
      <?php endif; ?>

          <!-- Pagination -->
          <ul class="pagination justify-content-center mb-4">
            <li class="page-item">
              <a class="page-link" href="#">&larr; Older</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item disabled">
              <a class="page-link" href="#">Newer &rarr;</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>

        <!-- Sidebar Widgets Column -->
        <div class="col-md-4">

          <!-- Search Widget -->
          <div class="card my-4">
            <h5 class="card-header">Search</h5>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Go!</button>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Categories Widget -->
          <div class="card my-4">
            <h5 class="card-header">Categories</h5>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Web Design</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">HTML</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Freebies</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">CSS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Tutorials</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Side Widget -->
          <div class="card my-4">
            <h5 class="card-header">Side Widget</h5>
            <div class="card-body">
              You can put anything you want inside of these side widgets. They are easy to use, and feature the new Bootstrap 4 card containers!
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: if it's a blank white page, you probably have a php error. Do you have error reporting turned on? What is the status of the page? 200 or 500 or something else?

Comment: first template in wordpress!... how can I turn error reporting? is there a function for that?

Comment: got it working. didn't even need error reporting turned on.. I fired up "web dev tools" in browser, then did a request for the page. Wola!!! error shows in "elements tab" not in console though... thanks

Comment: Oh cool. And just fyi, if you want to turn on PHP error reporting, you do that in the `wp-config.php` file in the root of your folder. Change `false` to `true` in `define('WP_DEBUG', false);`